How to print a clip directly from Ditto Clipboard manager?
Ditto is a great clip manager, but I cannot seem to find a way to print a clip directly (rather than save to file and then print that file).
If someone knows how to do this, please let me know.

Have you checked in the support forums or requested a feature for this product?


Open the Ditto app by pressing the combination (for me is ctrl+~).
Go to the desired clip, And press F3 Which is "View Full Description."
Right click on the text and press "Print."

